# Why interface is not implemented: List<string> is ICollection<string>

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, breeze-sharp

Consider the C# snippet:

```
    interface Contract
    {
        ICollection<string> Coll { get; }
    }

    class Implementation : Contract
    {
        public List<string> Coll { get; } //this declaration is mandatory for other reason
    }
```

Why Implementation does not implement Contract?

`List<string>` implements `ICollection<string>`

Real case

```
    //Entity Framework 
    public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
      ...
      public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }

    //Breeze.Sharp Entity 
    public partial class ApplicationUser : BaseEntity
    {
      ...
      public NavigationSet<Message> Messages
        {
            get { return GetValue<NavigationSet<Message>>(); }
        }
    }
```

How to find an interface that both classes implement?

Comment: simply because `Derived<MyType>` has nothing to do with `Base<MyType>`. Anyway even if it **would**: the interface is a contract, which must be fullfilled completely. So your signature has to match the interface exactly.

Comment: C# 9 introduces [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns), it might be helpful for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is a contract for consumers of your code. In your case that contract states: "there is a member called `Coll` which is of type `ICollection<string>`".

Implementations of your interface therefor have to follow it - that is they have to implement members exactly the same way the contract defines them - this is you need the exact same signature as of the interface.

Furthermore there´s absoluteley no way for a consumer to determine if or if not the member is of a more deerived type. In fact consumers shouldn´t care for that at all. That´s the point of an interface - to have an abstracttion about your actual implementations. So even **if** your implementation would work, clients have no way to use it:

```
Contract myContrac = new Implementation();
var list myContract.Coll;
```

As the interface states, `list` now is of type `ICollection<string>`. There´s no way to call any of `List<T>`s members, unless you explicitely cast to `List<string>`, which contradicts the point of abstractions and interfaces. This way you can easily exchange the actual implementation by a newer version for example, without clients need to do anything.

EDIT: to get an interface for both your classes you can use an explicit interface-implementation:

```
interface BaseEntity
{
    ICollection<Message> { get; }
}
//Entity Framework 
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; }
}

//Breeze.Sharp Entity 
public partial class ApplicationUser : BaseEntity
{
    public NavigationSet<Message> Messages
    {
        get { return GetValue<NavigationSet<Message>>(); }
    }
    BaseIntity.ICollection<Message> Messages { get => this.Messages; }
}
```

Comment: So the real problem to find an interface for those 2 classes has no solution?

Comment: @GioviQ You can use an explicit interface-implementation, see my edit